# Can't access sharepoint site from different PC

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, windows-server

I have checked other related questions but I did not get the answer. I have created the SharePoint site (Name is ProjectSite) for a Project. I have specified the port number as 1993 during SharePoint installation. I can see the site when I access it from the server PC. But when I try to access this site from different PC of same connection, page gives following errors.

I use following methods to access the site from different PC:

1) IP Address/sites/projectsite (Error: 404 File not found)

2) IP Address:1993/sites/projectsite (Opens the Central Administration Page)

3) ServerName/sites/projectsite (Requested URL was not found on this server)

[image]

4) ServerName:1993/sites/projectsite (The site can't be reached)

[image]

My IIS Manager shows the following screen. (I did not understand the meaning of this. I am posting the image because from other questions I got to know that the problem might be because of the ports mentioned in IIS Manager)

[image]

*I deliberately removed the server name as it can be used for some malpractice.(Sorry if it can't be used for malpractice, I am completely unaware of this networking world. So please don't feel offended)*

When I apply the third method mentioned above from server PC, I can access the site.

Please help me so that I can access this website from other PCs as well.

**Server Details:**

Windows Server 2012 R2

SharePoint Server 2013 SP 1

SQL Server 2012

Comment: if at ServerName/sites/projectsite (case 3) you get apache response you have some conflict, you should receive an response from IIS server rather than apache server.

Comment: @MarekSarad Okay. But how to solve this conflict? I don't have any idea about this server or any other networking issues.

Comment: First you need to identify where that apache response is coming from is it from your server (if so then unistal Apache server from it). But most probably it may be coming from some network device (maybe you have some netscaler or network accelerator) try to use the ping serverName to see from what IP you receive the response. if it is IP of the server then issue is most probably on your server, if it is other IP then issue is in another place.

Comment: @MarekSarad It is showing some different IP. In college, we have WiFi routers so it must be connected one of those. Now, how should I connect it to my server..??

Comment: ok I see, so the response is from some apache server which probably acts as an either DNS or Balancing, I am MS-shop guy so cannot add much more there. On SP site it may have something to do with the alternative access mappings. try to add mapping with IP. Or/and modify the Host file of your laptop/client to point your url to right server. There might be as well some firewall rules blocking your access. Ask your college IT team every environment is different and probably they know best.

Comment: @MarekSarad As you said I got connected to some WiFi router which was running Apache Server. I could access the site from different PC connection using LAN. Earlier I connected WiFi to my laptop to access it. But after connecting through LAN, I could access the site. Thanks a ton for your suggestions..!! :)

Comment: @MarekSarad Also can you please add this as your answer so that I can mark it as correct and close the question. Thanks again..!! :)

Comment: Glad I could help, I joined two comments into one answer. Happy Sharepointing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to identify where that apache response is coming from is it from your server (if so then unistal Apache server from it). But most probably it may be coming from some network device (maybe you have some netscaler or network accelerator) try to use the ping serverName to see from what IP you receive the response. if it is IP of the server then issue is most probably on your server, if it is other IP then issue is in another place.

On SP site it may have something to do with the alternative access mappings. try to add mapping with IP. Or/and modify the Host file of your laptop/client to point your url to right server. There might be as well some firewall rules blocking your access. Ask your college IT team every environment is different and probably they know best.